# Unit testing go code with fatal flows in a loop

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to add tests to a go cli code. 
The code has a lot of `log.Fatal` flows.
A bit of googling led me [here](https://blog.antoine-augusti.fr/2015/12/testing-an-os-exit-scenario-in-golang/), so I followed it and got the tests working.
But, the way my tests are, they are setup to run the function being tested in a loop with different arguments.

Here is the test code

```
func TestGetXXX_FatalFlow(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        varA string
        varB    string
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name     string
        args     args
        expected string
    }{
        {
            name:     "Scenario 1: varA and varB both blank",
            args:     args{},
            expected: "message1",
        },
        {
            name: "Scenario 2: varA and varB not blank but invalid",
            args: args{
                varA: "somevalueA",
                varB: "somevalueB",
            },
            expected: "message2",
        },
     }
    for _, tt := range tests {

        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {

            // Only run the failing part when a specific env variable is set
            if os.Getenv("BE_CRASHER") == "1" {
                GetXXX(tt.args.serverName, tt.args.address)
                return
            }

            // Start the actual test in a different subprocess
            cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "-test.run=TestGetXXX_FatalFlow")
            cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "BE_CRASHER=1")
            stdout, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
            if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            // Check that the log fatal message is what we expected
            gotBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)

            if !strings.Contains(string(gotBytes), tt.expected) {
                t.Fatalf("Unexpected log message. Got %s but should contain %s", strippedMsg, tt.expected)
            }

            // Check that the program exited
            cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "BE_CRASHER=0")
            err = cmd.Wait()
            if e, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); !ok || e.Success() {
                t.Fatalf("Process ran with err %v, want exit status 1", err)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is , I feel my method GetXXX is never called with the second pair of input variables, somehow the method GetXXX keeps getting called with just the very first pair of argument in tests array.
I am not so sure if its because this spawns a child process.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you walk through the code you'll see it's doing what you would expect:

1. Outer test run starts, loops over the test cases, env var isn't set, so for each iteration, it forks out a new `go test` process.
2. New process starts running the same test function, which **loops over the test cases**, env var *is* set, so for each iteration, it calls `GetXXX`, which crashes.

You'll see that at step 2 here, for each iteration, the child process runs the first test case, which crashes, and it never gets to the second case. The loop iteration in the parent is irrelevant - it never passes any parameters of the test case to the child process, so the child has no idea which test case the parent thinks it's testing. It iterates the cases itself again, but only manages to execute the first before crashing.

Generally I would advise against this sort of structure (`go test` forking out a new `go test`), and I would also advise against having fatals anywhere in your code. For 99% of cases, your functions should be returning an `error` when something goes wrong. For truly unrecoverable fatal errors, you should be using `panic`, which you can then test for using `recover`. `log.Fatal` (which I'm guessing is what you're using) just prints a log message and then calls `os.Exit`, which makes it nearly impossible to test for, as you've found.

If structuring the program correctly really, truly isn't an option, then as a last resort, you could do something like this (untested but I hope it gets the point across):

```
crasher := os.Getenv("BE_CRASHER")
if crasher == "" {  // Parent process
    for idx := range tests {

        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {

            // Start the actual test in a different subprocess
            cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "-test.run=TestGetXXX_FatalFlow")
            cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), fmt.Sprintf("BE_CRASHER=%d", idx))
            stdout, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
            if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            // Validate child process did as expected yadda yadda
        })
    }
} else {  // Child process
    idx, err := strconv.Atoi(crasher)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tt := tests[idx]
    GetXXX(tt.args.serverName, tt.args.address)
    return
}
```

This changes it up by having the parent iterate the test cases and when it forks the child it uses the env var to *tell the child which case to run*. The child then runs *only* the specified case.

Comment: I like your answer and I do feel this code needs to be re-factored to avoid `log.fatal` calls. Thanks